# When does one use 同埋 and 然後 in Cantonese?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, cantonese, conjunction

A long time ago, I asked a Hong Kong colleague how to order food by saying "and" or "and then". She taught me the structure is basically something like "我要薯條同埋一個漢堡包." But I also listened to some audio from Pimsleur that used the word 然後 as "then" in a similar way. If I remember correctly it was something like "我去呢度，然後大學." When are both words usually used in Cantonese? I think when I used to speak Mandarin, 然後 was a pretty good catch-all for both situations, but I'm not sure it works that way in Cantonese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the sequence is not important, use “同埋” in lieu of “and”

eg:

what dim-sum did you eat?

你食咗咩點心?

i ate shrimp dumplings, steamed pork dumplings, **and** steamed beef balls

我食咗蝦餃，燒賣，**同埋**山竹牛肉

the sequence of which one you tasted first is, unimportant to the asker

“然後” use it as “afterward”, when the sequence is clear

eg

where did you go this afternoon?

你晏晝去咗邊?

firstly, i wandered in the sogo (department store), **afterward**, i went to eslite (bookstore), then had afternoon tea at lee gardens [a shopping mall]

我先響 sogo 打個 round，**然後**去咗誠品，跟住响利舞臺食 tea

this saying provide adequate info to reconstruct the routing

if, one answer: 我去咗 sogo, 誠品, 同埋利舞臺

the info provided is, . . . less precise

have fun :)

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, just curious, may i ask, why, you’re interested in cantonese 

Comment: 1) I live in Hong Kong, so it is useful to learn (especially in my area). 2) It is important for my research to know the differences between "standard" Mandarin and Cantonese as spoken languages, even if that dichotomy isn't so neat.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, imo, compare to mandarin, cantonese is more related to old chinese, and middle chinese. the most significance differences is: cantonese still has entering tone (入聲), that any rhyme books in the past are valid, and useable. further, cantonese preserves ancient terms used in classical / literary chinese. 

Comment: Yeah I've read a bit on that. I think *The Oxford Handbook of Chinese Linguistics* and *A History of the Chinese Language* document this pretty well from what I remember.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, great, if you can read chinese, have a look of books 廣府話救亡, 廣東俗語正字考, 粵語詞匯溯源  btw, these’re not academic publications. further, if, and only if you’re able to read literary chinese, i may recommend a book list 

Comment: Haha my Chinese isn't quite at that level to ready literary Chinese, but I appreciate the recommendations. I can understand a good deal of modern Chinese, but not sure that makes much of a difference.